# $rootScope.app is undefined

Tags: angularjs

Gente,

Pedi ajuda para resgatar o valor de uma variável num arquivo js pelo $rootScope que fica no controller da minha aplicação. Minha intenção é resgatar na página hmtl esse atributo para poder exibir na tela a versão do sistema.

Ao rodar a aplicação ocorre a mensagem: $rootScope.app is undefined

infoBuild

```
var VERSAO_SISTEMA = '01.02.00.002';
```

Controller

angular.module('webApp')
    .controller('ImrController',

```
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $translate, $http, $timeout, Log, WebServiceX, Alert, Analytics, Error, Utils, WebServiceRest, WebServiceT) {

    Log.debug("ImrController()");
    Analytics.trackEvent('controller','ImrController');
    $scope.container = {};     
    $rootScope.currentview.id = 'iMR';
    $rootScope.currentview.group = 'IMR';
    $rootScope.currentview.title = 'IMR';
    $rootScope.currentview.icon = 'fa-list-alt';
    $rootScope.currentview.locked = false;
    $rootScope.currentview.menu = true;
    $rootScope.currentview.description = 'IMR';
    $rootScope.app.version.id= VERSAO_SISTEMA;

    //Preenchimento da data da ultima carga
    $http.get('/siigf/ws/imr/dataUltimaCarga').
    then(function(response) {
         $scope.dataUltimaCarga = response.data;
    });
```

Html

### {{app.name}}{{app.version.id}}

{{app.version.name}}

Também importei no index.html o arquivo infoBuild.js

O projeto esta em angular JS

Obrigada!

Comment: Você injetou o $rootScope no seu modulo?

Comment: Olá boa tarde.
Primeiramente não é bom utilizar rootscope ou scope, prefira utilizar o padrão de implementação com angular.extend.
Por exemplo ao invés de :